# What is a dataset in the context of databases?

Tags: mysql, database

What is a dataset in the context of databases?
Is it all records of a table or is it one specific record ?
Thanks

Comment: have you read what Wikipedia says about a dataset? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_set

Comment: The general definition is pretty applicable a "database context", I think: "a collection of related sets of information that is composed of separate elements but can be manipulated as a unit by a computer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the set of records that are pulled from DB. say you query `select * from table where age > 20`, then it returns a set of records, which is nothing but the data set.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, a *data set* is a set of rows.

Speaking in a mathematical context, a data set is a set of tuples (records or key-value sets) that fulfill certain given conditions.

In a relational database context, a data set is the result of any `select` sentence. This result can have none (empty data set), one or many rows, depending on the definition of the `select` sentence.